# why decimal number is always at 0 in my database?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

Here is my problem: I have an ASP.NET MVC application, I have a book list (isbn, author, title, price, photo and summary) and I created a form to be able to add a new item (book) in my list.

It's added OK to my database and it appears in my list (my view) but when I add a price with a decimal number, it always shows 0 in my database and my view.

Example, if I write `25.50` the code prints `0`.

How to make it display the right price in decimal?

This is my method added to my controller

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Ajouter(Livre livre)
{
    //ajouter un client dans la table Clients de la base de données
    this._context.InsertLivre(livre);

    //Sélectionner tout les livres de la table Livres de la base de données  et les afficher dans la vue
    return View("Liste", this._context.SelectLivres());
}
```

And this is my method for insert book

```
public void InsertLivre(Livre livre)
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(this.ConnectionString))
    {
        // requete pour ajouter un client dans la table client
        string sqlStr = "INSERT INTO Livres(Isbn, Auteur, Titre, Prix, Quantite, Photo, Resume) " +
               "VALUES (@isbn, @auteur, @titre, @prix, @quantite, @photo, @resume)";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlStr, con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        // ouverture de la connexion
        con.Open();

        // donner les valeurs a parametre
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("isbn", livre.Isbn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("auteur", livre.Auteur);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("titre", livre.Titre);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("prix", livre.Prix);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("quantite", livre.Quantite);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("photo", livre.Photo);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("resume", livre.Resume);

        // exécuter la requete
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        // fermeture de la connextion
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

//here is my class livre

```
 public class Livre
{
    [DisplayName("Isbn :")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Le champ Isbn est obligatoire", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    [RegularExpression("^[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}$", ErrorMessage = "Le champ \"Isbn\" doit être composé de lettre et de chiffre seulement")]
    public string Isbn { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Auteur :")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Le champ auteur est obligatoire", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    [RegularExpression("^[A-Z][A-Za-zéè ]{3,29}$", ErrorMessage = "Le champ Auteur doit contenir seulement des lettres et commencer par une majuscule")]
    public string Auteur { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Titre :")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Le titre est obligatoire", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    [RegularExpression("^[A-Z][a-zéè]{4,100}$", ErrorMessage = "Le champ titre doit contenir seulement des lettres et commencer par une majuscule")]
    public string Titre { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Prix :")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Le prix est obligatoire", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    public double Prix { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Quantité:")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Le champ quantité est obligatoire", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    [RegularExpression("^[0-9]{1,4}$", ErrorMessage = "Le champ \"Quantité\" doit être numérique seulement")]
    public int Quantite { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Photo :")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Ce champ est obligatoire", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    public string Photo { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Résumé:")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Ce champ est obligatoire", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    public string Resume { get; set; }
```

Comment: What is the **datatype** of that column in the database table?? Also: you should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Comment: And what is the type of `livre.Prix`?

Comment: the type of this colunm in my database is decimal, in my models is double

Comment: What is the precision and scale of the database decimal column?

Comment: oh sorry i use money not dec ...

[Prix] [money] NOT NULL,

should i use decimal?

Comment: Take a look at [SQL-CLR Type Mapping - Numeric Mapping](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/linq/sql-clr-type-mapping#NumericMapping). It is appropriate to use `decimal` on the C# side for `money` on the SQL side. It sounds like you have other things going on here. Start by replacing `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("prix", livre.Prix);` with `cmd.Parameters.Add("prix", SqlDbType.Money).Value = livre.Prix;` to see if that helps. If not, include the `class` definition for `Livre` in your question because it may be something silly like `public decimal? Prix {get; set;}`

Comment: thank you

my definition for Livre
public string Isbn { get; set; }
        public string Auteur { get; set; }
        public string Titre { get; set; }
        public double Prix { get; set; }
        public int Quantite { get; set; }
        public string Photo { get; set; }
        public string Resume { get; set; }

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Comment: ok sorry i will update my post ;)